# Unit test functions that use vscode extension api functions

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, mocha.js, vscode-extensions

I am trying to figure out a way to unit test functions, which include helper functions included in the vscode extension api, such as **showQuickPick**. Example usage: `vscode.window.showQuickPick(['one', 'two']);`.

I have been trying to stub and mock those, but while I am not sure if that's even the right way to go, I haven't had any luck with it anyway.

A complete example could look something like:

**logic.js**

```
export async function unitTestMe(): Promise<string> {
  const quickPickAnswer: string = vscode.window.showQuickPick(['one', 'two']);
  return quickPickAnswer;
}
```

**logic.test.js**

```
import { unitTestMe } from './logic';
describe('should return user input', () => {
  test('', () => {
     const expected: string = 'expect me';
     const actual: string = await unitTestMe();
     expect(actual).to.eql(expected);
  })
})
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "haven't had any luck" when you stubbed or mocked showQuickPick()? Did you have errors or are you just concerned that your solution might be "bad smelling code"?

Comment: Well. I didn't figure out how I could mock/stub showQuickPick as an inner  call of **unitTestMe()** to vscode extension api, and I think maybe that was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I did it in my current project: I created a class called VscodeEnvironment where I wrapped Vs Code API (A layer of indirection)

```
export class VscodeEnvironment {
    public getActiveTextEditor(): vscode.TextEditor{
        return vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    }

    public showErrorMessage(message: string): void {
        vscode.window.showErrorMessage(message);
    }

    public showQuickPick<T extends QuickPickItem>(items: T[] | Thenable<T[]>, options?: QuickPickOptions, token?: CancellationToken): Thenable<T | undefined> {
        return vscode.window.showQuickPick(items, options, token);
    }
}
```

In my unit tests, I set up a VscodeEnvironment stub to return a resolved promise:

```
let vscodeEnvStub = moq.Mock.ofType(VscodeEnvironment);
vscodeEnvStub.setup(x => x.showQuickPick(moq.It.isAny(), moq.It.isAny())).returns(()=>Promise.resolve<QuickPickItem>(fakeItem));
```

I'm using typemoq, but it should not be very different in other mocking frameworks

Comment: Part 1: The layer of indirection has solved part of my problem! However, I need to remove the following function from my code:

     `await commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', uri);`

so that I can unit test the flows using jest which as the vscode api mocked out as follows:

    `jest.mock('../../src/vscode/VscodeEnvironment', () => jest.fn());`

The code is refactored to `VscodeEnvironment` as:

        `public static async executeCommand(command: string, ...rest: any[]): Promise<any | undefined> {
        return commands.executeCommand(command, rest);
    }`

Comment: Part 2: Only other change is to make the indirection layer a singleton:

    `public static getInstance(): VscodeEnvironment {
        if (!VscodeEnvironment.instance) {
            VscodeEnvironment.instance = new VscodeEnvironment();
        }
        return VscodeEnvironment.instance;
    }`

The following error message is thrown when I try to call `executeCommand` with the new flow:

> No extension context

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is called "dependency injection":

At first, try to separate dependencies from your code and then do it in a way that you can set these dependendies from outside of your function or class or prototype.

i.e.

```
 function unitTestMe(vsCodeExtensionApi) {
    const quickPickAnswer = vsCodeExtensionApi.window.showQuickPick(['one', 'two']);
    return quickPickAnswer;
 }
```

or if you have a class

```
class MagicClass {
   constructor(vsCodeExtensionApi) {
      this._vsCodeExtensionApi = vsCodeExtensionApi;
   }

   unitTestMe() {
       const quickPickAnswer = this._vsCodeExtensionApi.window.showQuickPick(['one', 'two']);
       return quickPickAnswer;
   }
```

Now you can pass a stub or mock to unitTestMe like

```
const stub = {
   window : {
      showQuickPick = function(param) {
         // return some stuff
      }
   }
}

unitTestMe(stub)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to mock the `showQuickPick` method, the following code will do so:

```
vscode.window.showQuickPick = (items: string[] | Thenable<string[]>) => {
  return Promise.resolve('Continue') as Thenable<any>;
};
```